# MASS package LDA - error in assessing accuracy of the prediction when using a loop: Error in table(): all arguments must have the same length

Tags: r

I'm trying to use a linear discriminant analysis (LDA) with the MASS package in R to determine if species within communities are more discriminable than random sets of species (with multiple traits predicting species identity).

When I run the LDA on the full dataset (all communities together), no problem. My problem comes when I try to use loops to run the LDA on each community separately.

I have 19 communities. I make a list of 19 called new2; each item in the list represents a single community with all of it's associated species and their scores for various traits. I use a loop to run the LDA on each item this list new2[[i]] and put it in the object c.dfas[[i]]. No problem here.

I then try to run a loop to assess the prediction accuracy (% correct for each category of Species) and put the summaries into coms.sum[[i]] list I should get a list of 19, with the prediction success for each community. Instead, I get this error:
Error in table(new2[[i]]$Species, c.dfas[[i]]$class) : 
  all arguments must have the same length

When I run length(new2[[i]]) I get 26,
and when I run length(c.dfas[[i]]) I get 5.

I understand that these are different lengths but I am unsure of how to solve it/re-write the loop to make this work. I have successfully run this exact (or I guess almost exact) code before with a different dataset no problem, so I know it is possible to get the prediction success from these lists in some way.

When I run length(new2[i]) I get 19,
and when I run length(c.dfas[i]) I get 19.

How do I get to the species stored in new2 and the class stored in c.dfas to be the same length?

````
data1 <-read.csv("Apr4_DFA.csv")

#load packages
library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(lattice)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_classic())

#######################_Full_Model_############################

# Linear Discriminant Analysis with Jacknifed Prediction
full <- lda(Species ~ Pixelwise.Shannon.Entropy + Average.Local.Entropies + sclFWMC +
              Local.Patch.Covariance + logAGM + Pixelwise.Differential.Entropy +
              Patchwise.Differential.Entropy + Global.Patch.Covariance + logPMD +
              logWDC + Colour.Diversity + pattern + logH1, data = data1, na.action="na.omit", CV=TRUE)

full # show results

# Assess the accuracy of the prediction
# percent correct for each category of Species
ct_full <- table(data1$Species, full$class)
diag(prop.table(ct_full, 1))
# total percent correct
sum(diag(prop.table(ct_full)))

#full model 91%

###################_Run DFA on Each Community_######################

#see levels in factor community
levels(data1$Community)
#see number of levels in factor community
length(levels(data1$Community))  

#take the levels of community and put it in coms
coms <- levels(data1[,"Community"])
coms
#sample 1 community of coms without replacement
sample(coms,1, replace=F)

#make empty list of 19 put it in new2
new2 <- list(19)

#take each randomly drawn community and put them in new2
for(i in 1:19){
  temp <- sample(coms,1, replace=F)
  new2[[i]] <- data1 %>% filter(Community %in% temp) 
  new2[[i]] <- droplevels(new2[[i]])
  rm(temp)
}

new2  

#create empty list of 19 called c.dfas
c.dfas <- list(19)

#run dfa on each community subset and put it in c.dfas
for(i in 1:19){
  c.dfas[[i]] <- lda(Species ~ Pixelwise.Shannon.Entropy + Average.Local.Entropies + sclFWMC +
                       Local.Patch.Covariance + logAGM + Pixelwise.Differential.Entropy +
                       Patchwise.Differential.Entropy + Global.Patch.Covariance + logPMD +
                       logWDC + Colour.Diversity + pattern + logH1, data = data1, na.action="na.omit", CV=TRUE)
}
c.dfas
unclass(c.dfas)

#make empty list of 19 called coms.sum
coms.sum <- list(19)
#make another empty list of 19 called ct.c.dfas
ct.c.dfas <-list(19)

################ this is where I get the error ###################
#loop to assess the accuracy of the prediction % correct for each category of Species
#put the summaries of total % correct in the coms.sum list
for(i in 1:19){
  ct.c.dfas[[i]] <- table(new2[[i]]$Species, c.dfas[[i]]$class)
  diag(prop.table(ct.c.dfas[[i]], 1))
  coms.sum[[i]] <- sum(diag(prop.table(ct.c.dfas[[i]]))) 
}

coms.sum

length(new2[[i]]) #26
length(c.dfas[[i]]) #5 ```
````

Comment: Why are you using sample instead of processing each community? You select one community of 19 each time through the loop so you will not analyze all the communities and will analyze some more than one time. Use `split` to create a list of communities and then use `lapply` to run `lda` on each one.

Comment: I ran the loop so that I don't have to re-type out the lda 19 times. My list is 19 and as you can see from this line: sample(coms,1, replace=F), the communities are not being resampled. Each item in the list corresponds to 1 community and all communities are sampled. 

I'm not super familiar with the apply functions. could you write out some sample lines of code?

Comment: `sample(coms, 1, replace=FALSE)` considers all 19 communities and picks one. The next `sample(coms, 1, replace=FALSE)` has no way to know which community was picked earlier so it considers all 19 communities and picks one. Some will never get picked and some will be picked multiple times. Construct a function that specifies the `lda` call and use the function with `lapply` without a sample data set I cannot be more specific.